# Can Inner Product be complex?

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces, inner-products

Judging from [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) the result of Inner Product is a field is $V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb F$. Where $\mathbb F$ can be a Complex Number:

> In this article, the field of scalars denoted $\mathbb {F}$  is either the field of real numbers $\mathbb {R}$ or the field of complex numbers $\mathbb {C}$.

But since $\langle x, x \rangle \ge 0$, I don't understand how Complex results are possible - $\mathbb C$ isn't an ordered field, so it can't be compared to $0$. So how can we both have a Complex Inner Product and have it greater than $0$?

Comment: read its [Complex coordinate space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Complex_coordinate_space) subsection, it's done via conjugation

Comment: The non-negativity condition applies only when the two arguments involved are identical. The inner product for *distinct* arguments is allowed be non-real.

Comment: @Blue, thanks for clarification. So there's no "type-safety" here? We say it's Complex in general case, but we _rely_ on the fact that it's actually always Real for $\langle x,  x\rangle$..

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev: *"We say it's Complex in general case, but we rely on the fact that it's actually always Real for $\langle x, x\rangle$."* Correct. Now that you mention it, I suppose it would be considerate of the Wikipedia contributors to state that explicitly. (After all, so far as the bare statement "$\langle x, x\rangle >0$" goes, it "could be" that the equal-argument product maps to *any* orderable subset of the target field. But that's a little silly. In any case, the use of "positive" in the name of that property would seem to limit the intention to "positive and *real*".)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have a complex vector space $V$ with an inner product $V\times V\to\Bbb C$ where $\langle x,x\rangle$ always happens to be real. For instance, if $V=\Bbb C^2$, the standard inner product is
$$
\langle (a,b),(c,d)\rangle=a\bar c+b\bar d
$$
and we see here that if $(a,b)=(c,d)$, then the result of the above multiplication is $|a|^2+|b|^2$, which is very much a real number.

I say "happens to be real", but that is actually no coincidence. Note in your Wikipedia article that inner products are required to be not symmetric, but *conjugate symmetric*. I.e. swapping the order of the two entries conjugates the result: $$\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$$
This gives, for any vector $x$ in the space, that
$$
\langle x,x\rangle=\overline{\langle x,x\rangle}
$$
which means the product has to be real. And now, since we know it's real, the requirement that this number is positive for any non-zero $x$ makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

What that means is that, for each $x\in V$, $\langle x,x\rangle\in[0,\infty)$.

For instance, if, in $\Bbb C^2$, you define$$\bigl\langle(z_1,w_1),(z_2,w_2)\bigr\rangle=z_1\overline{z_2}+w_1\overline{w_2},$$then, if $x=(z,w)$,$$\langle x,x\rangle=\bigl\langle(z,w),(z,w)\bigr\rangle=|z|^2+|w|^2\in[0,\infty).$$